Terraform google-beta GCP filestore source backup attribute issue
I am trying to manage a rollback of a GCP filestore using terraform. I am using google-beta provider. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/filestore_instance
When I am providing source backup attribute and running terraform plan, it shows the instance has update in place but when I run apply it throws the error that the new instance name is not found.
  ~ resource "google_filestore_instance" "filestore_instance" {
        create_time      = "2024-07-09T23:54:32.786600984Z"
        effective_labels = {
            "application" = "confluence"
            "environment" = "test"
            "terraform"   = "true"
        }
        id               = "xxxx"
        labels           = {
            "application" = "confluence"
            "environment" = "test"
            "terraform"   = "true"
        }
        location         = "us-east1-b"
      ~ name             = "atlassian-confluence-test-restore" -> "atlassian-confluence-test-filestore"
        project          = "yyy"
        protocol         = "asas"
        terraform_labels = {
            "application" = "confluence"
            "environment" = "test"
            "terraform"   = "true"
        }
        tier             = "BASIC_HDD"
        zone             = "us-east1-b"
        file_shares {
            capacity_gb   = 1024
            name          = "conf_test_share"
            source_backup = "projects/abc/locations/us-east1/backups/confluence-backup-26june2024"
            nfs_export_options {
                access_mode = "READ_WRITE"
                anon_gid    = 0
                anon_uid    = 0
                ip_ranges   = [
                    "xx/23",
                    "xx/23",
                ]
                squash_mode = "NO_ROOT_SQUASH"
            }
        }
        networks {
            connect_mode = "DIRECT_PEERING"
            ip_addresses = [
                "xxxx",
            ]
            modes        = [
                "MODE_IPV4",
            ]
            network      = "xxxx"
        }
    }

Apparently, terraform cannot do in place restores. It needs to create a new filestore instance and then it restores the backup there.
When I re run the pipeline then it shows it is creating new instance and restoring the backup so i have to run plan and apply twice in order to rollback.
Anybody comes across this situation? I am not sure how to resolve this.
